# python dictionary: KeyError but the key exists when iterating

Tags: python, dictionary

```
nobj = Name.lookup(self.name)
for k,v in Animal.animals_of.iteritems():
        if k == nobj:
            print 'found %s with %s' % ( nobj, k)
            print v

print Animal.animals_of[nobj]
```

OUTPUT:

```
found abc with abc
[<Animal object at 0x7f9b00aa2290>]

   print Animal.animals_of[nobj]
KeyError: <Name object at 0x7f9afe5824d0>
```

Question:
when i am iterating through `Animal.animals_of`, i can find `nobj`.

But when i am doing a lookup on `nobj` , it cant find it

Animal obj has its own `__cmp__`.
Does python dictionary use different compare method or something?